# how to use Xinclude correctly to see data of all children?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I have the following XML docs:

doc_1: (Xincludes the second document)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
<xi:include href="doc_2.xml" parse="xml" /> 
</document>
```

doc_2:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <para>This is a paragraph.</para>
```

My code looks as follows:

```
from lxml import tree

tree = etree.parse("stck_oflow_test.xml") #load file
tree.xinclude()                                                  #recursively includes files

root = tree.getroot()


def print_root():
    for child in root:
         print (child.tag, child.attrib, child.text)
    
print_root()
```

The output is good for my purposes; para {} This is a paragraph.

But, here's where the problem is, if I change doc_2 into a file that has data in the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<para>

    <length>177</length>
    <weight>63</weight>

</para>
```

then, the output no longer contains the contents of doc_2. Running the same python code results into the output:

para {}

How to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with XInclude. That part works.

`for child in root` iterates over the immediate children of `root`. In this case, there is one child: the `<para>` element.

To iterate over all descendants (including `<length>` and `<weight>`), you can use `for child in root.iter()` instead. That will result in the following output:

```
document {} 
  
para {} 
  
length {} 177
weight {} 63
```

Comment: Did this answer help?